# Stiffness matrix for 3-nodes beam elements FEM (M+N)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, classical-mechanics, finite-element-method

Considering a 2-nodes beam element, having 3 dofs per node, making it 6 per element, this element will be studied according to a M+N model, where both bending and traction would be taken into consideration.

As mentioned, each node has 3 dofs :

- u : x-axis translation
- v : y-axis translation
- theta : section rotation

[image]

For this 2 nodes element, I found the representation of the stiffness matrix for both bending (Km) and traction (Kn).

[image]

[image]

The element's stiffness matrix would be a sum of the two.

---

My question is related to the 3-nodes version of the element, being a plane shell, having the same dofs, 3 per node, 9 per element.
**What would be the representation of the element's stiffness matrix in this case ?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's very exciting that you are going to build an FEM Model from scratch! The stiffness matrix in your case is simply:
$$
K_m+K_n
$$
But this stiffness matrix only applies to each edge's **local coordinate system** respectively, while the variables shown in the triangle are inevitable in a **global coordinate system**.

A conventional routine would be:

(1) first construct the local stiffness matrix (6 DOF per node) matrix per edge：[image]

But don't forget to transform it into a **global coordinate system** by $$
K=\mathbf{v}^T k' \mathbf{v}
$$ 
where the $12\times 12 $ matrix $\mathbf{v}$ represents the transformation according to the edge's direction.

(2) Virtually construct a full matrix $A$ whose dimension is $3N\times 3N$ (truss) or $6N \times 6N$ (frame), where $N$ denotes the number of nodes. Then add every edge's local matrix onto $A$ (the nodal index in the full matrix should be consistent with that in local matrix).

(3) distinguish the free nodal displacements $\mathbf{x}_a$ from the constrained ones $\mathbf{x}_c$ according to boundary conditions. Then $A$ can be partitioned into:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{aa} & A_{ac}  \\
A_{ac}  & A_{cc} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}_{a}   \\
\mathbf{x}_{c} 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{a}   \\
F_{c} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It's a magic if you get a full rank square matrix $A_{aa}$. Then solve

$$ 
A_{aa}  \mathbf{x}_{a} =  F_{a}  
$$

to find out the unknown displacements $\mathbf{x}_{a}$.

(4) The displacement $\mathbf{x}_{a}$ in the last step is represented in a global coordinate system. One need to go back to each edge's local coordinate system to compute its axis forces and bending moments.

Comment: I'm wondering if the local stiffness matrix shouldn't be $(9,9)$ since each element consists of 3 nodes, each having 3 DOFs (x-disp, y-disp and rotation)

Comment: It's simply $K_m+K_n$ (equivalent to eliminating irrelevant rows and columns out of the standard full matrix). But this stiffness matrix only applies to each edge's local coordinate system respectively, while the variables shown in the triangle are inevitable in a global coordinate system.. Besides, there is a typo in your $K_m$.

Comment: I just want to make sure we are indeed talking about the same thing. What I'm looking to achieve is a FEM representation of a beam, with plane 2D elements, triangular elements to be precise, where each triangle is made of 3 nodes, each nodes having a number of DOFs, which in this case are equal to 3 DOFs (U,V, ROT Z). If I'm understanding this right, you gave indications for a truss, which is made of 1D elements, having 2 nodes each with 6 DOFs.